# logic voltage divider problem

Tags: digital-logic, voltage-divider

[image][https://www.partsim.com/embed/#102528](http://%3Ciframe%20width='500'%20height='300'%20frameborder='0'%20scrolling='no'%20src='https://www.partsim.com/embed/#102528'%3E%3C/iframe%3E)

I made the following cirucit. Pin 1 2 and 3 are connected to microcontroller output pins. Pin 4 is where I want to measure a voltage. Only one pin (1,2,3) is high (3.3V) at a time.

My intend was to get 3 different voltages (pin 1 750mV, pin2 500mV, pin3 250mV). But of course this circuit does not work.

How could I achieve something like this?

Best Regards!

edit: I does not work because I get 0 V for Pin3 High, -250mV for Pin2 and 250mV for Pin1

---

Thank you all.

I did a combination of the suggestions of Eugene Sh an st2000. Took the resistor ladder with diodes to prevent current into the Pins.

Comment: Please embed your circuit into the question.

Comment: sorry the link did not work.

Comment: If the inactive pins are low, there will be current flow into them. You should take that in account. Alternatively you might want to make them tri-state.

Comment: I thought that 200k Ohm should be large enough for that reason.

Comment: It's the ratios here not the absolute values which play a role.

Comment: Okay I guess then this "attend" is not useable at all.

Comment: You can augment it with opamp similar to this :http://ikalogic.cluster006.ovh.net/wp-content/uploads/8bitdac_2.jpg

Comment: how can you ask for this `pin 1 750mV, pin2 500mV, pin3 250mV`, when you have this `Only one pin (1,2,3) is high (3.3V)`?  .... it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: pin1: High -> Pin4 750mV , Pin2: High -> Pin4 500mV etc :)

Comment: Suggestion: Study the [Resistor Ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder) page on Wikipedia.

Comment: "I get ... -250mV for Pin2" - your MCU can only output 0V or 3.3V, yet you get -250mV??? How is that possible?

Comment: "Only one pin (1,2,3) is high (3.3V) at a time" - you cannot have more than one pin high at a time? If not, _why_ not?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It is not hard to understand if you read precisely and look at the circuit.

Comment: @BruceAbbott that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intend was to get 3 different voltages ... How could I achieve
>   something like this?

Consider tying 4 resistors of known values together and measuring the voltage at that point.  Connect 1 of the 4 resistors to ground.  Connect the other 3 resistors each with a unique resistance to 3 different GPIO pins of the embedded processor.  Most embedded processor GPIO pins are programmable as output-high, output-low & inputs.  Program only 1 of the 3 different GPIO pins as an output-high.  Program the other 2 as high impedance inputs.  The measured voltage should reflect the voltage divider created between the pin configured as an output-high and ground through the 2 resistors which make up the divider.  Repeat this pattern for the other 2 GPIO pins.  The voltage should be unique for each of the 3 GPIO pins if you have chosen 3 unique resistor values for the resistors connected to the GPIO pins.

If the embedded processor is not capable of programming pins as high impedance inputs, add a diode in series with each of the 3 resistors already attached to the 3 different GPIO pins.  Arrange the diode such that the Anode is closest to the GPIO pin.  Now when 1 of the 3 GPIO pins is programmed to the high state that pin's diode will be forward biased and will influence the measured voltage where all the resistors converge.  The other 2 GPIO pins are programmed to the low state and the connected diodes will be in reversed bias and will not allow current to flow.  Therefore the other 2 GPIO pins will not influence the measured voltage where all the resistors converge.  Program a different GPIO pin high while all other GPIO pins are low and epeat the voltage measurement.  Do this for each GPIO pin.

Comment: @egrape: Note that any load you apply to the mid-point of a voltage divider will be seen as an additional resistor in parallel with the bottom resistor, so will affect the voltage at that point.  If the top resistor is a high value, like 200K, you can only draw a tiny current from the voltage divider without making a significant change in the output voltage.

Comment: I do not have the possibility to change the Pin Direction unfortunatly.

Comment: @epgrape, you can add a diode to each digital output pin that is forward biased when the pin is high and reversed biased when the pin is low.  I can add this to my answer if you wish.